# Valor no se actualiza inmediatamente usando useState en el render

Tags: reactjs

Estoy intentando actualizar un valor con useState pero no se actualiza inmediatamente
El valor se actualiza correctamente cuando lo visualizo en la consola pero no en el render dentro de un bucle. Como lo actualizo en el bucle?

Contexto

```
var itemsList = [];
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const pushProduct = useCallback(async (id, name, price, quantity) => {
setItems(items => [...items ,{id, name, price, quantity}])
}, []);

const updateItem = useCallback(async (_id, op=true) => {
    let itemsCopy = [...itemsList];

    itemsList[0].forEach((_item, value, map) => {
        if(_item.id === _id) {
            let itemSelected = {..._item};
            let quantity = Math.floor(_item.quantity)

            op ? quantity += 1 : quantity -= 1;
        
            itemsCopy = itemSelected;
        }
        setItems(items => itemsList[0]);
    }, []);
})

useEffect(() => {
    itemsList.push(items)
}, [items]);
```

JSX

```
  var cart_is_empty = true;

  const cartContext = useContext(CartContext);

  cartContext.items.length == 0 ? cart_is_empty = true : cart_is_empty = false

{!cart_is_empty && cartContext.items.map((_item, id) =>
          <Table.Row key={id}>
            <Table.Cell>
              <div>
                <Button onPress={()=>cartContext.updateItem(_item.id, false)}>
                  <Minus size="24"/>
                </Button>
                <Text css={{margin: "10px"}}>{_item.quantity}</Text>
                <Button onPress={()=>cartContext.updateItem(_item.id)}>
                  <Plus size="24"/>
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        )}
```

cuando actualizo desde `pushProduct` se actualiza pero no desde updateItem

Comment: no podes agregar el JSX del componente para poder probarlo?

Comment: @infinit3Loop__  Listo

Comment: es improbable el codigo, no aclaras de que libreria sacas los componentes Table, Text y Button, la primera parte del código es el contexto?? lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ Si, la primera parte del codigo es el contexto, respecto a los componentes lo puse de mas, creo que es inecesario puesto que no afectan en nada. Da igual si los reemplazo por simple tags html.